# How to host online my postgresql database for my flutter app

Tags: postgresql, flutter

I built an app in flutter for my school association using posgresql, node.js, typescript... To built the backend on the app (typescript) I follow a tutorial that explain basics of backend, however I found nothing on how put my postgresql online on a server and connect it to my flutter app.

If anyone has a link or can explain how to proceed I would appreciate.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can host your postgresql database on Ubuntu server.

[How to Install and Set Up PostgreSQL Database on Ubuntu 20.04](https://linuxhint.com/install_postgresql_-ubuntu/)

After installing postgres database , you can use package postgres: ^2.4.3 in flutter.

https://pub.dev/packages/postgres

Comment: Thanks Piotr ! 
I will try it this thing and do an update ;)

Comment: Do you have any update? How did you go about hosting your db?

Answer (score 0):

You Can host your ***PostgreSQL-DB*** freely on Heroku using Heroku **Postgres Add-on**.